# DUMPBIN doesnt show all functions

Tags: c++, windows, dll, system-calls, dumpbin

I used `DUMPBIN` utility of Microsoft Visual C++ on the following program. I know for sure that the call to `remove` eventually calls the Microsoft system call of `DeleteFileW` from the `kernel32.dll` (I confirm this call with another tool).
So why when I apply `DUMPBIN /imports` on the .EXE of the following program I don't see the `DeleteFileW` system call?

How do I see the system call of `DeleteFileW` using `DUMPBIN` ?

Thanks,
Gilad

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char* fileName = "gilad.txt";

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10*1000));

    if (remove(fileName) != 0)
        cout << "Remove operation failed" << endl;
    else
        cout << *fileName << " has been removed." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect you have done a dynamic build, try a static build `/MT` or `/MTd` see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not call `DeleteFileW`, it calls `remove`. Presumably from `msvcrt.dll`. Yes, after that `msvcrt.dll` calls `DeleteFileW` for you, but that part does not appear in your executable file.

(And `dumpbin` works on a single file, it does not track dependencies of other files)

> How do I see the system call of "DeleteFileW" in DUMPBIN output?

You would have to run `dumpbin` on a file actually referring `DeleteFileW`. Which is not the code above, but another one you may create using WinAPI, or just as an experiment, run it on `msvcrt.dll`.

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to mention a different "approach" I took to solve this issue:

(Using Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017)

**1)** **Compiled** the above code using the `cl` command:

`cl main.cpp`

Note: In order to compile it straight from the Developer Command Prompt, I have removed the first line of code (`#include "stdafx.h"`).

**2) Output** "almost" all possible output of the `dumpbin` utility using the following command ( assuming your exe is called `main.exe` and you have created an output text file called `myDumpbinOutput.txt`) using the command:

`dumpbin /ALL /RAWDATA:NONE /OUT:myOutput.txt main.exe`

Note: The `/RAWDATA:NONE` eliminates the RAWDATA that the `/ALL` option includes (no need for that).

**3)** Used "naive <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>" of a text editor (Notepead++) to **search**,and indeed saw the call to the system call you were looking for, `DeleteFileW` under the `KERNEL32.dll` import section of the output.